# Get text from a div in an iframe and insert into another div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I need to get the contents of a DIV #time in an Iframe and output it in a DIV #clock. But my code seems not to work. What am I doing wrong.

```js
$( "#iFrame" ).contents().find( "#time" ).appendTo( "#clock" );
```

```html
<body>

<div class="clock" id="clockbox">
    <a class="clock-box">
      <span class="sml">Time: </span>
      <span id="clock" class="sml"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" >
  <iframe id="iFrame" src=""></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Do the host page and the iFrame have the same origin?

Comment: @peeebeee yes they have the same origin.

Comment: If you're loading the contents of the iFrame dynamically, maybe it hasn't loaded when your code runs.

Comment: @peeebee, how do I make the code run after iframe load

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the iFrame hasn't loaded when your code runs, trigger it from the `load` event.....

```
$('#iFrame').on('load', function(){
    $( "#iFrame" ).contents().find( "#time" ).appendTo( "#clock" );
});
```